# Selling old DVD-burned porno movies for less

Tags: copyright

Normally DVD movies involve a license with rights to the actresses and other people.

In the late 80s a license was heavily protected mostly by stakeholders like Brazzers. So I bought a porn movie for $22.99 can i now sell it for $3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can sell it for whatever you can get for it.  The license allows you to watch the DVD.  If you sell the DVD, you won't be able to watch it - but the buyer will.

This is same principle that books are subject to copyright, but there is nothing stopping you selling your books second-hand to a dealer.

Comment: Assuming that the DVD was legally copied.